# How do I register the system in RealityKit ECS with a custom component

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos, reality-composer-pro

I'm trying to create custom components in Reality Composer Pro and make it do something in the update loop.

I currently added a component in Reality Composer Pro like this.

[image]

I created a new system for this component in the Component script.

```
import RealityKit

// Ensure you register this component in your app’s delegate using:
// RotateAroundComponent.registerComponent()
public struct RotateAroundComponent: Component, Codable {
    // Name used to uniquely identify the component type. It can differ from the struct name.
    public static var componentName: String { "RealityKitContent.RotateAroundComponent" }

    // This is an example of adding a variable to the component.
    var count: Int = 0

    public init() {
            
    }
}

class MySystem : System {


    // Define a query to return all entities with a MyComponent.
    private static let query = EntityQuery(where: .has(RotateAroundComponent.self))


    // Initializer is required. Use an empty implementation if there's no setup needed.
    required init(scene: Scene) {
        
    }


    // Iterate through all entities containing a MyComponent.
    func update(context: SceneUpdateContext) {
        context.scene.performQuery(Self.query).forEach { entity in
            // Make per-frame changes to each entity here.
            print(entity)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to register both the `RotateAroundComponent` and `MySystem` using `registerComponent()` and `registerSystem()` calls according to the documentation.

However, I don't understand where I have to call these functions since these classes are never in scope in the App swift files.

Tried to reference them in the App file

[image]

Tried to create an AppDelegate to see if that fixes it

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm kind of new to Swift programming.

Answer (score 1):

I found that we can reference the classes as long as they are public by using,

RealityKitContent prefix.

[image]